# Difference between 'Home sharing' and 'Network sharing'

Tags: itunes, home-sharing

When I like to share my iTunes library, I have to options to do so.

1. Home sharing via my Apple ID
2. Network sharing.

What is the difference between these to? Are there any advantages or disadvantages or missing features comparing these two methods?

Comment: On which iTunes version ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler 11.1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While both options offer the possibility of *streaming* the content of up to five iTunes libraries through a *home network*, it's only through **Home Sharing** when you are able to actually **import** the content into your own iTunes Library.

Even more, when you use a computer on your *Home Sharing network* to download an item from the iTunes Store, you can have the item download automatically to other computers on your *Home Sharing network*.

Other big difference is that **Home Sharing** lets you **stream** content from your iTunes library into your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple TV (2nd and 3rd generation), whilst **Network sharing** don't.

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot stream content from my library to my iDevice using Network sharing? So I could remote my library but not stream the content to the iDevice?

Comment: @DaPhil Yes, only through **Home Sharing** you are able to **stream** content to the iDevices / Apple TV.

Comment: @DaPhil Content import can only be done with **Home Sharing** and between **Computers**.